# Not able to override consumer config in azure iot hub sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, azure-iot-hub, confluent-schema-registry

I'm making an AzureIoT Hub sink connector using the Microsoft connector class. I am using an AVRO converter on the connector.

I want to use KafkaAvroDeserializer, on the consumer to deserialize the Avro data coming from the topic but I'm unable to override value. deserializer value.

I'm using consumer.override.value.deserializer in the logs.
Could anyone please suggest a way out?

My config is below :

```
"consumer.value.deserializer": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeSerializer".
```

I'm getting the deserializer as byte array and I want it to be kafkaAvroDeserializer

I am making a azure iot hub sink connector. And, I'm getting error deserializing avro data from kafka topic.

```
{

    "config": {

        "IotHub.ConnectionString": "connectionString",

        "IotHub.MessageDeliveryAcknowledgement": "None",

        "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "server",

        "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1","connector.class":"com.microsoft.azure.iot.kafka.connect.sink.IotHubSinkConnector",

        "consumer.override.auto.register.schemas": "true",

        "consumer.override.id.compatibility.strict": "false",

        "consumer.override.latest.compatibility.strict": "false",

        "consumer.override.schema.registry.url": "registryUrl",
  
"consumer.value.deserializer":"io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeSerializer",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",

        "name": "TEST1",

        "tasks.max": "1",

        "topics": "testtopicazure3",

        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",

        "value.converter.auto.register.schemas": "true",

        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "registryUrl"

    },

}
```

Getting error :

```
Caused by: 

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error 

deserializing Avro message for id -1

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: 

Unknown magic byte!
```

Answer (score 0):

In Connect, you **only** set `value.converter`, not consumer client deserializers

```
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
```

And all your `consumer.override` prefixes should be `value.converter`, instead

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/self-managed/userguide.html#configuring-key-and-value-converters

Comment: I have added more details in the question. Could you please see and help me out with the error? @OneCricketeer

Comment: "Unknown magic byte" means your data was never produced using Confluent Avro serializer